# UITapGesture not recognised on the simulator when tapping a UIImageView

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to display a new image based on a user tapping the image view. I have added a UITapGestureRecognizer on top of the UIImageView which has been defined a "displayPhoto" and connected it as an outlet to the view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayPhoto: UIImageView!

@IBAction func changeImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    displayPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "myimage")
}
```

The sent action is listed as follows:

[sent actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssIKS.jpg)

When I run the app and click on the image, nothing happens. I've even tried to make the first line of the IBAction function a fatal error but nothing happens. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

[The full view and connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoeuA.jpg)

[Tap Gesture Recognizer Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBFv6.jpg)

Comment: The UIImageView already has "User Interaction Enabled" checked

Comment: Also done. If I hover on the filled circle next to the outlet definition, it highlights the tap gesture recogniser on the scene dock

Comment: When I hover over the sent action, it highlights the whole view controller. I have just named it view for the sake of the example..

Comment: Have changed the view to be "New item" and pasted a photo showing the reference outlet

Comment: Added photo of window connections and sent actions

Comment: The sent action or the Referencing outlet connection? Apologies, I am new to this.

Comment: Ok removed all connections...how should I connect/integrate the Tap Gesture Recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you try; clean your project

> command+option+shift+K

The first case cannot be empty

You should add a picture.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
       displayPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "firsCase")
    }
```

Comment: The UIImageView has a default display photo

Comment: It is created as nil you created. You have to set the default picture under it. Please You try

Comment: The attributes inspector has an image selected for this